# Problemas al realizar envío masivo de notificaciones iOS

Tags: java, ios, push-notification, payload

Estoy teniendo problemas al hacer envío masivo de notificaciones para dispositivos iOS, cuando realizo envíos para pocos dispositivos (1-20 más menos) funciona sin problemas, pero cuando tengo que realizar un envío masivo (3000+) me está dando el siguiente error:

> [2017-04-27 15:12:07] ERROR (Notificaciones:347) - IOS: Error en envio
>   notificaciones - CommunicationException: 
>   javapns.communication.exceptions.CommunicationException: Communication
>   exception: java.net.ConnectException: Expir tiempo de
>   conexiConnection timed out)     at
>   javapns.communication.ConnectionToAppleServer.getSSLSocket(ConnectionToAppleServer.java:156)
>     at
>   javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.initializeConnection(PushNotificationManager.java:106)
>     at
>   javapns.notification.transmission.NotificationThread.runList(NotificationThread.java:215)
>     at
>   javapns.notification.transmission.NotificationThread.run(NotificationThread.java:199)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Expir tiempo de conexiConnection timed
>   out)  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:576)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:635)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.(SSLSocketImpl.java:423)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
>     at
>   javapns.communication.ConnectionToAppleServer.getSSLSocket(ConnectionToAppleServer.java:153)
>     ... 4 more

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
private static  void realizaEnvioIOSLista (final List<DispositivoDto> dispositivos, final String textoES, final String textoCA, final String textoEN, final String tipoNotificacion){       
        //El metodo de multithread payload hace return unicamente cuando todos los hilos han finalizado de poner las notificaciones.
        //Como no queremos esperar a que termine ponemos el codigo en un hilo separado para que pueda continuar y no se quede colgado el WS.            
        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){              
                try {           
                    final List<String> idsDispositivos = new ArrayList<String>();                   

                    final String keystore = XmlUtils.dirCertIOS + XmlUtils.nomCertificado;
                    final String password = XmlUtils.password;
                    final boolean production = XmlUtils.production;

                    //Obtenemos los ids de los dispositivos
                    for(DispositivoDto r : dispositivos)
                         idsDispositivos.add(r.getIdDispositivo());                  

                    // Creamos el payload con los campos que necesitemos   
                    PushNotificationPayload payload = PushNotificationBigPayload.complex();

                    /* Customize the payload */ 
                    payload.addAlert(textoES);    
//                  payload.addSound('default');
                    payload.setContentAvailable(true);

                    payload.addCustomDictionary("es", textoES);
                    payload.addCustomDictionary("en", textoCA);
                    payload.addCustomDictionary("ca", textoEN);
                    payload.addCustomDictionary("tiponotificacion", tipoNotificacion);  

                    List<PushedNotification> notifications = new ArrayList<PushedNotification>();

                    if(idsDispositivos.size()<= 200){   
                        notifications = Push.payload(payload, keystore, password, production, idsDispositivos);

                    // Si hay mas de 200 dispositivos creamos diferentes hilos utilizando el multithread payload
                    } else {
                        // Decidimos cuantos hilos vamos a crear y usar
                        int threads = 1;

                        if(dispositivos.size() > 200) {
                            threads = (int) Math.ceil(dispositivos.size()/200);
                        }

                        // empezamos los hilos, esperamos a que terminen, y se coge la lista de notificaciones
                        notifications = Push.payload(payload, keystore, password, production, threads, idsDispositivos);

                    }

                    //Gestion de los resultados del envio de notificaciones 
                    int dispEliminados = 0;
                    int dispNotificados = 0;

                    for (PushedNotification notification : notifications) {
                        if (notification.isSuccessful()) {
                            dispNotificados ++;
                            // Apple accepta la notificacion y debe enviarla
//                          logNot.info("Notificacion para el dispositivo " + notification.getDevice().getToken() + " enviada correctamente.");
                        } else {
                            String invalidToken = notification.getDevice().getToken();

                            //obtenemos el indice del dispositivo en la lista de dispositivos
                            int index = idsDispositivos.indexOf(invalidToken);

                            //obtenemos la informacion del dispositivo a borrar
                            Integer usuario = dispositivos.get(index).getUsuario();
                            String idHardware = dispositivos.get(index).getIdHardwareDis();

                            //quitamos el dispositivo de nuestra BD
                            aBD.unregisterDispositivo(usuario, invalidToken,idHardware);
                            dispEliminados ++;
                            logNot.info("IOS: Eliminado el dispositivo: " + usuario+ " - " + idHardware + " - " + notification.getDevice().getToken());

                            //Encontramos mas informacion sobre el problema ocurrido
        //                  Exception theProblem = notification.getException();
        //                  theProblem.printStackTrace();

                            //If the problem was an error-response packet returned by Apple, get it
                            ResponsePacket theErrorResponse = notification.getResponse();

                            if (theErrorResponse != null){
                                logNot.info("IOS: " +theErrorResponse.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }   
                    logNot.info("IOS: Dispositivos Notificados correctamente: " + dispNotificados);
                    logNot.info("IOS: Dispositivos Eliminados: " +dispEliminados);

                } catch (CommunicationException e) {
                    logNot.error("IOS: Error en envio notificaciones - CommunicationException: ",e);
                } catch (KeystoreException e) {
                    logNot.error("IOS: Error en envio notificaciones - KeystoreException: ",e);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    logNot.error("IOS: Error en envio notificaciones - JSONException: ",e);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logNot.error("IOS: Error en envio notificaciones",e);
                }
            }
        };

        thread.start();
    }
```

¿Estoy haciendo algo mal? ¿Cual es el número máximo de dispositivos y de conexiones al servidor de Apple se pueden hacer? Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He encontrado la solución a mi problema, el código funciona bien, después de hablar con los administradores de sistemas hemos podido ver que era un problema de configuración de los servidores, ya que según este enlace de [apple](https://support.apple.com/es-es/HT203609) para poder realizar envíos de notificaciones hay que tener en cuenta lo siguiente:

> Para utilizar el Apple Push Notification Service (APNS), los clientes
>   con Mac y dispositivos iOS deben tener una conexión directa y
>   persistente a los servidores de Apple.

Por lo que:

> Si utilizas Wi-Fi detrás de un firewall o un Nombre de punto de acceso
>   privado para datos móviles, conéctate a puertos específicos.
>   Necesitarás una conexión directa sin proxy a los servidores del APNS
>   en estos puertos:
>
> - Puerto TCP 5223: para establecer la comunicación con el Apple Push Notification Service (APNS).
> - Puerto TCP 2195: para enviar notificaciones al APNS.
> - Puerto TCP 2196: para el servicio de retroalimentación del APNS.
> - Puerto TCP 443: se requiere durante la activación del dispositivo y para el retroceso solo en Wi-Fi, en casode que los dispositivos no
>     puedan llegar al APNS en el puerto 5223.

Además:

> Los servidores del APNS utilizan el equilibrio de carga, por este
>   motivo los dispositivos no siempre se conectan a la misma dirección IP
>   pública para las notificaciones. Es recomendable que tu dispositivo
>   tenga acceso a estos puertos en todo el bloque de direcciones
>   17.0.0.0/8, asignado a Apple.

Por lo que todo se ha resuelto configurando el firewall para que permita estas conexiones. Espero que le sirva de ayuda a alguien.